# Java Selenium how to set a dynamic variable for new driver

Tags: java, selenium, if-statement, variables, block

I know that it is in not possible in java to use variables from conditional Blocks.
But I dont know what to do. When I do it like this I get an error for the code after the if statements:

```
public static void startDriver(String preferredBrowser) throws Exception{
    Webdriver driver;

    if(preferredBrowser.equals("Firefox")){

    } 
    else if(preferredBrowser.equals("Edge")){

    }
    else{
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",  driverPath);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
        options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);

        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    }
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get(website);

}
```

This what I tried to fix it but now it does open me two drivers at once:

```
public static void startDriver(String preferredBrowser) throws Exception{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",  driverPath);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    if(preferredBrowser.equals("Firefox")){

    } 
    else if(preferredBrowser.equals("Edge")){

    }
    else{
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",  driverPath);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
        options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);

        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    }
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get(website);

}
```

I hope you can help me out.

Best Regards

Christian

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want that I can use the variable "driver" for several webdrivertypes.
But I can't use variables which are declared in a condition block, so tried to put it outside.

Comment: I would need to declare "Webdriver driver" without opening the webdriver.
So I dont get any error below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize driver type for each `preferredBrowser` as following:

```java
public static void startDriver(String preferredBrowser) throws Exception{
    Webdriver driver;

    if(preferredBrowser.equals("Firefox")){
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    } 
    else if(preferredBrowser.equals("Edge")){
            driver = new EdgeDriver();
    }
    else{
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",  driverPath);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
        options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);

        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    }
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get(website);
}
```

Comment: oh ... I got the errors because I didn't fill up the other statements. Ups xD I thought Java just wants to annoy me. At least my code was right.... Thank you for helping my stupidy ^^